# Show off your scripts

Tags: feature-request

I think [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) should have a tab like this:

[image: Top]

Here:

[image: Location]

Like [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) does. I think it should be called `Creations` or something similar. People can show off there scripts and things they made there like you can do in [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) but, it doesn't have to use the API. There should also be a reputation limit like `125+` or something so it isn't filled with spam posts.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Apps serves a ***completely*** different purpose than Stack Overflow.  With Stack Apps, scripts and questions are focused around the user of the Stack Exchange API, so it would make *some* sense to allow users to show off what they've done.  In context of making Stack Exchange work easier for them, some may argue it to be *necessary*.

With Stack Overflow, users are using whatever language, framework, or methodology they feel like.  There's no reason or rhyme to it, and there doesn't need to be, either.  Thus, asking people to post their favorite snippets of code is...well, useless, especially given that their "favorite" snippets may not be immediately applicable to others' cases.

So no, I don't think this feature should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thats why I said: "like you can do in StackApps but, it doesn't have to use the api."

Comment: Not just snippets but links to projects they made on github.

Comment: Yes @NoahCristino, but you seem to have missed my point.  The reason it works for Stack Apps is *because* they use a central API and have a central focus point.  It *couldn't* work for Stack Overflow because Stack Overflow is literally *incapable* of unifying in such a way.

Comment: Ok @Makoto I just thought it would be cool to be able to show off what you made because when you answer questions it would be cool to see what the end result was to the project you helped.

Comment: @NoahCristino but how does this meet that goal? As suggested it doesn't have a link to a specific post. And how is it better than just putting a repo link in your post/profile?